# Certain UNICODE characters (astrological symbols) not displaying on Chrome on Mac

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, unicode, character-encoding

It seems there are two sets of astrological characters that you can use, but for some reason, when I try to use them on Chrome, only the emoji-variation displays.

[image: screenshot of the two options available]

I notice this is only true on Chrome when I am using my Macbook (but not on Safari on Macbook, and not on Chrome on Windows). Is anyone able to explain why this is? And better yet, is there a workaround to having it display properly on the website I am building? My HTML uses the latter, transparent background characters which can change color along with the rest of the text it is displayed with, but again, on my Macbook using Chrome, it only ever displays the emoji variant.

EDIT/UPDATE:
The problem might be visible to other people who visit [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astrological_symbols) on astrological symbols on Wikipedia. Can anyone using Chrome on a Mac confirm that they notice the same pattern?

Chrome:
[image]

Safari:
[image]

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: @Manfred Sure! How much would be helpful to see? I just input the character like so ```<div class="text libra" style="color:plum">♎︎</div>``` all throughout. If you'd rather see more, let me know, but hopefully this is sufficient for context! :)

Comment: I wonder if it's worth noting that on sites like CodePen, in their code writing field, or also in the code block in my above comment, it displays as I intend (non-emoji), but in the comment writing field here on StackOverflow, in the address bar of the browser, and on the website itself, it only displays as an emoji. I've tried setting the font-family to monospace as that seemed to be the common theme, but that did nothing... :(

Comment: The style definitions would be relevant, too...  I wonder whether the font is explicitly specified. If it is not, different browsers may chose different fonts. You could actually check in the dev tools which one is effectively used on both systems.

Comment: What font are you using - or are you relying on the the font that the browser picks up as a default can support these symbols in the way you want?

Comment: @Manfred Ah, sorry! Originally, I had tried remedying it with ```font-family: monospace;``` but that didn't work, so I tried importing the Google Font 'Fira Mono' instead, and while both monospace and Fira Mono displayed fine on Windows using Chrome, again... still emojis on Chrome using Mac :(

Comment: @AHaworth I've tried importing other fonts too, but as I mentioned in my reply to Manfred, that didn't seem to work at all :(